# How to escape double quotes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know that to escape special characters in Haskell we can use `\"`, so if I try to pass as parameter:

```
parseString :: String
parseString = "{\"coord\":[\"D\",\"7\"],\"result\":\"HIT\",\"prev\":{\"coord\":[\"A\",\"10\"],\"result\":null,\"prev\":null}}"
```

to the function

```
take 7 parseString
```

everything works fine, but I'm wondering is there are shorter way to produce the same result, without putting escape symbol `\"` everywhere (imagine big JSON)?

For example, Python has this:

```
>>> s = """my string with "double quotes" blablabla"""
'my string with "double quotes" blablabla'
```

Comment: There are package that use Haskell's *quasiquotes*, to help produce raw strings.

Comment: Depending on the application, you could also consider whether ASCII double quote characters are really the best choice. For instance many markup and dynamical languages (though not JSON) also allow single quotes for strings. And, if the quotes are actually supposed to appear in human-readable text, then you should probably use Unicode `“ U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` and `” U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`. All of these can appear in Haskell string literals without any escaping.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You escape double quotes with a backslash (`\"` in a string), like:

```
"\"To be, or not to be\" - William Shakespeare"
```

The above can of course be rather cumbersome in case you need to write a lot of double quotes. Haskell enables *quasiquotes* a way that is used by many Haskell packages to develop "mini-languages" inside Haskell. Quasiquotes are to the best of my knowledge not specified in the Haskell report, so it is not really a "Haskell feature", but the most popular compiler (GHC) supports this. A package like [**`raw-strings-qq`** [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/docs/Text-RawString-QQ.html) allows you to make use of this feature to write raw strings, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Text.RawString.QQ(r)

quote = [r|"To be, or not to be" - William Shakespeare|]
```

this thus produces strings like:

```
Prelude Text.RawString.QQ> [r|"To be, or not to be" - William Shakespeare|]
"\"To be, or not to be\" - William Shakespeare"
```

QuasiQuotes are not only used to produce raw strings. In Yesod for example there are a few mini-languages to define HTML/CSS/JavaScript templates in Shakespearean languages (`hamlet`, `lucius`, `cassius`, `julius`). It is typically used if expressing something in "vanilla" Haskell would take a lot of work, whereas writing it in a specific language makes it easier.

Comment: Speaking about Yesod and Shakespeare, `shakespeare` has `Text.Shakespeare.Text` with `text` and `stext` quasiquoters for this purpose.

Answer (score 10):

Use `\"`. There is no other way in vanilla Haskell. Eg:

```
λ> putStrLn "\""
"
λ> putStrLn "my string with \"double quotes\" blablabla"
my string with "double quotes" blablabla
```

Further information on this can be very easily found in the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) (See §2.6 on character and string literals, particularly the definition of *charesc*.).

However, by using Template Haskell, a metaprogramming system for Haskell, you can create raw strings. From [the package page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/docs/Text-RawString-QQ.html):

```
λ> :set -XQuasiQuotes
λ> import Text.RawString.QQ
λ> let s = [r|\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|]
λ> s
"\\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}"
λ> [r|C:\Windows\SYSTEM|] ++ [r|\user32.dll|]
"C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM\\user32.dll"
```

Similarly you can type the strings above:

```
λ> [r|my string with "double quotes" blablabla|]
"my string with \"double quotes\" blablabla"
```

Note that in Haskell source files this requires that you use the `{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}` pragma at the top of your file.